# Pâte Brisée, Sucrée and Sablée

Tags: baking, baking-powder

Why is it necessary "to make holes" when a Pâte Brisée, Pâte Sucrée or Pâte Sablée or go to the oven if they are not made with baking powder?

Comment: Different terminology, but same question [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22497/why-and-when-do-you-need-to-dock-dough).  I'm not sure what baking powder has to do with it, other than baking powder is used for things that are expected to puff up/rise; these doughs are not expected to puff, hence the pricking.

Comment: Even without baking powder there will be steam (due to the water in the dough) which needs to get out or it might form bubbles, separating individual layers / flakes of dough. The term is "docking". See more in the duplicate question.